# How to, in A.py, extend class defined in B.py that is used by C.py

Tags: python, pygame

I want to extend some classes from pygame, such as `Surface` and `Rect`. I could make use of inheritance, but this would not affect the calls made from pygame itself, that is, all the methods that return `Rect`s and `Surface`s.

For example, the statement `screen = pygame.display.set_mode()` returns a `pygame.Surface` and allows me to draw things on the screen via `screen`. If I create a class `MySurface(pygame.Surface)` and do something like `screen = MySurface()`, I obviously get the new functionality, but the ability to manipulate the screen is lost.

Is there some way of extending the functionality of such classes and applying it to external calls without having to modify any external files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like pygame is a C extension module which means your ability to extend its classes is going to be limited. In general you're only going to be able to extend the classes the module intends you extend. In pygame the `Sprite` and related classes are designed to be extended, but the `Surface` and `Rect` classes do not appear to be. You could still extend these classes, but the extensions would be largely only be useful in your own code, as you noted.

You can try encapsulating the the classes you want to extend. Something like this:

```
class MySurface(object):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self._surface = surface

    def blit(self, source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0):
        return self._surface.blit(source, dest, area, special_flags)

    # code to forward all the other members 

    def myblit(self, source, dest):
        # code that modifies source and dest
        return self._surface.blit(source, dest)

mysurf = MySurface(pygame.display.set_mode())
```

You should also consider if the `Sprite` class is really what want to be extending. Based on the other questions regarding extending or encapsulating `pygame.Surface` here the `Sprite` class is what they really want.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly my idea (except for the last line - how didn't it come to my mind?), but it seemed like the "wrong" way to solve the issue. Since my goal for now is to add some handy drawing functions, I guess it really is `Surface` what I want to extend, even though I'll make use of `Sprite` as well.

Maybe you'll want to change that first "def" to "class" and remove the leading space in the last line. :)